# Sanity.io GROQ - Retrive document by highest reference count in other documents

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, sanity, groq

I have a tag document that looks like

```
{
  name: 'tag',
  title: 'Tag',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'label',
      title: 'Label',
      type: 'string',
    }
  ]
}
```

And page document that looks like

```
{
  name: "page",
  title: "Page",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      title: "Title",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "tags",
      title: "Tags",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: "reference", to: [{ type: "tag" }] }],
    }
  ]
}
```

And another article document that looks like

```
{
  name: "article",
  title: "Article",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      title: "Title",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "description",
      title: "Description",
      type: "text",
    },
    {
      name: "tags",
      title: "Tags",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: "reference", to: [{ type: "tag" }] }],
    }
  ]
}
```

**I am unable to figure out how to get the tags with the highest reference count used across pages and articles**

An extension of this question would be to get the top 10 highest tags used across the site.

I've been struggling for a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely accomplish this by constructing a query that first gets all `tags`, then uses the `count` function to further filter them. Something like the following:

```
*[_type == 'tag'] {
  ...,
  'totalReferences': count(*[_type in ['page', 'article'] && references(^._id))
} | order(totalReferences desc) [0...10]
```

This may not be very performant in very large datasets, though.